# Cuda: synchronize one kernel function out of n

Tags: c++, cuda, synchronization

I'm wondering about this question: is there a way to synchronize just one kernel function? For example if I have something like this:

```
function_1 <<< dimgrid, dimblock >>> (param1, param2, param3);
funckion_2 <<< dimgrid, dimblock >>> (param4, param5, param5);
function_1 <<< dimgrid, dimblock >>> (param6, param7, param8);
```

is it possible to know if the second `function_1` has finished before the first?. Could the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` function help me for this problem? I need this because I have to reuse some of the resources (`param-i`) for other kernel functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you launch each kernel into its own stream, then you can use [cudaStreamSynchronize](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g82b5784f674c17c6df64affe618bf45e) on the stream running the kernel you want to wait on. So something like:

```
//stream creation for stream1, stream2
...
function_1 <<< dimgrid, dimblock, 0, stream1 >>> (param1, param2, param3);
funckion_2 <<< dimgrid, dimblock, 0, stream2 >>> (param4, param5, param5);
function_1 <<< dimgrid, dimblock, 0, stream1 >>> (param6, param7, param8);

cudaStreamSynchronize(stream1);
```

would probably do what you want.